# To read a .json into a data.table in R, use fread or jsonlite in 2020?

Tags: r, json, data.table

I'm wondering if there's a current best-practice for data.table users for reading .json files. I saw this post from 3+ years ago where the recommendation was to use jsonlite, and I am curious if that's still the case, or if there's a magic data.table function that does it well (perhaps even fread somehow)?

I have a tricky import where I'm dealing with many, many zipped .jsons inside other zipped files, and I feel like the way fread deals with zipped files would be nice to have.

Anyways, I'm not trying to get into the detail of my coding situation just here, if that's okay, just looking for this nudge in the right direction, and then I'll ask a more detailed question with examples etc. after I've tried to make things work with whatever is suggested here.

Comment: Probably not `fread`. From what I know, it's written for delimited files only(although it still works for fixed width files). I don't think any functionality has been planned for other formats

Comment: @rohit Any idea if there's another function that's particularly good with data.table? Or should I be searching for jsonlite or another alternative?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. But as long as you can get a dataframe as an output you can always use `setDT` if you want to use `data.table`